# как написать программу которая считает сумму чисел кратных 6 и оканчивающихся на 2. на вход подаются числа и последовательность заканчивается 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a=int(input())
k=0
s=0
while a!=0:
    a=int(input())
    if a%10==2 and a%6==0:
        k=k+1
        s=s+a
print(s(k))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите более полное условие. Что подаётся на вход? Количество чисел или сразу числа (до тех пор, пока оне не будут равны `0`)? Вы можете дополнить свой вопрос, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: `res = sum(list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0 and x % 6 == 0, [int(i) for i in input().split()])))`

Comment: @entithat `x%2==0` надо заменить на `x%10==2`

Comment: @n1tr0xs, да-да, попутал.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать так:

```
a=-1
s=0
while a:
    a=int(input())
    if a%10==2 and a%6==0:
        s+=a
print(s)
```

Comment: а зачем мы присваиваем a "-1"?

Comment: @limona это чтобы в цикл без ошибок зашло, можно любое другое число, кроме 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input('Number: '))
s = 0
while (a < 0) or (a > 0):
    if (a % 6 == 0) and str(a)[-1] == '2':
        s += a
    a = int(input('Number: '))

print(s)
```

Comment: перевод числа в строку довольно долгая операция, проверка остатка гораздо быстрее